# Error installing qr-js

Tags: node.js, qr-code

Installing `qr-js` on `node.js`

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: "python" tag is unrelated I think?

Comment: @mertyildiran I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Your question is not related to Python language, so you should remove `python` tag. Actually, it looks like a bug in a library you are trying to install (does it support Windows at all?).

Comment: Always check the github issues page of the module to check if the bug is already documented there or not. It appears to be a similar bug to this - https://github.com/neocotic/qr.js/issues/37 Maybe, this link will help you - https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows

Answer (score 0):

It says right there in the output that `node-gyp rebuild` failed. Make sure you have the proper pre-requisites, as listed on [the library page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp), under the "On Windows:" section.

Additionally, I found [this possible solution](https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/) for this library not working under Windows. The problem appears to be because of some wrong dependencies.

> The core of the problem is that node-gyp is no longer being actively developed  and so it has some old dependencies that a modern development env might not have.

You have there some instructions to fix it. Hopefully it'll work for you too